# date format in mysql query add extra hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a time counter that count time to a due date that based on date that saved in the database, since I want to make it readable in every browser, I called the date by this format `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as date` but time that occur on the time counter is +7 from 8 AM that saved in the database into 3PM..

can someone tell me how to get exact date from the database?

Comment: Just a hunch, you are in the Pacific timezone?

Comment: I'm in Asia actually

Comment: I think you are using timestamp to store data in table change it to datetime should solve the issue.

Comment: yes, it's UTC+7 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in select statement ,you will get exact datetime:

```
DATE_FORMAT( DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 7 HOUR),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as date
```